# Bind a Div Value to a Salesforce Field in Salesforce lightning-record-edit-form in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

How can I bind `div` value to a Salesforce field? I have a custom form using `lightning-record-edit-form` for updating records and I used `div` instead of `lightning-input-field` as I want the current value to be displayed without the text box but at the same time, its value can be changed dynamically via js calculations and saved in a custom field named `Sum__c`. Also, adding a `read-only` attribute in `lightning-input-field` does not update the value upon submit, neither `lightning-output-field`.

So far, expected value in console.log changes but upon clicking the update button, value is not saved to the custom field.

Meanwhile, here are the codes I have:

**portion of html file**

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
         <label>Custom Field</label>
         <div>{customFieldValue}</div>
     </div>
     <lightning-button label="Update"type="submit">/lightning-button> 
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

**portion of js file**

```
@track customFieldValue; 
@track customRec = {CustomObject__c:""};

total() {
    var input1;
    var input2;
    this.customFieldValue = parseInt(input1) + parseInt(input2);
    this.customRec.Sum__c = this.customFieldValue;
    console.log('this.customRec.Sum__c' + this.customRec.Sum__c);     
}

handleSuccess( event ) { 
   this.dispatchEvent(
      new ShowToastEvent({
         title: 'success',
         message: 'Success！',
         variant: 'success',
      }),
   );
}

handleSubmit() {    
     event.preventDefault();
     const fields = event.detail.fields;
     fields.Sum__c = this.customFieldValue;
     this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your requirement should be achievable with `lightning-input-field` or `lightning-output-field` also. Based on your comment, looks like you the code snippet provided is partial and you are already using `lightning-*-field` in your code for other fields.*

`lightning-button` should be placed within/before the end tag of `lightning-record-edit-form` (see code snippet below). ***The record edit form wouldn't wire itself to a button that is declared outside***. [*Also, I guess you were closing tag of record edit form was missing `/`, but that may have been a typo while posting this question*]

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
     <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-2">
         <label>Custom Field</label>
         <div>{customFieldValue}</div>
     </div>
     <lightning-button label="Update" onclick={handleSubmit} type="submit"></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

The `console.log` statements work because they are placed in the JS functions/ client side event handlers and they output the local/ client side values.

If you are using `DIV` elements and the fields are not displayed using `lightning-*-field`, you might want to consider overriding the default submit behavior. In the HTML file, wire a custom submit event handler by adding the attribute `onsubmit={handleSubmit}` to `lightning-record-edit-form` and add the following event handler method to the JS file.

```
handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
   const fields = event.detail.fields;
   // Write your own code here to update fields here using 'fields.<fieldName> = <value>'
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```

I suggest you update the code snippet provided in the question to give better picture about your component, if the above mentioned doesn't help you.

Comment: I used `lightning-input-field` but there's a text box in it. The requirement is that value should be printed in display without box around it. I tried to add a `read-only` attribute, but value is not captured upon save, same with `lightning-output-field`. I used `div` as it is more flexible. With regards to the lightning button, I have other fields embedded inside `lightning-input-field` but they are saving just fine even though button is outside `lightning-record-edit-form`.

Comment: Though flexible as it may be, I have a problem with saving the value of `div` in custom field as I do not know how to bind its value to the custom object's field. I hope this clarifies my issue.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I see that you are already using custom submit event handler, but that's missing `event.preventDefault();` and you are not manipulating the fields in it. May be that's causing the problem? Also, are you sure that having button outside the record form works? [_I doubt it would and the code snippet is not complete. So, I'm not sure how it works_].

Comment: Yes, button outside lightning-record-edit-form` works. I just omitted those embedded in `lightning-input-field` for simplicity purposes and I don't have any problem regarding saving of its values. Meanwhile, I will check your suggestion for now.

Comment: I modified the code but upon submit, there is a js error.

Comment: Also, would this line `this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);` also cover those fields (embedded in lightning-input-field) that are currently having no problems during update?

Comment: Yes, the existing `lightning-input-field`s would be covered. `event.detail.fields` allows you to cherry pick and additionally update the fields you want. About the JS error, did you add the event attribute to `lightning-record-edit-form`? It's hard to point out the root cause without looking at your updated code.

Comment: Not sure about that part. Here is the current version of `lightning-record-edit-form`: `<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>`. As for the `handleSubmit` , here's how I bind it to my update button: `<lightning-button label="Update" onclick={handleSubmit} type="submit"></lightning-button>`

Comment: I updated the code, can you check it? What should I modify exactly on the `lightning-record-edit-form` part?

Comment: Use this `<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="CustomObject__c" record-id={recordId} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>`. For button, use this `<lightning-button label="Update" type="submit"></lightning-button>` and move it inside the record edit form.

Comment: I modified the code based on your recommendation, but upon update, a `Sorry to Interrupt` error displays , then immediately calls the toast success message and redirects to record detail page. I inserted also `console.log` statement after `fields.Sum__c = this.customFieldValue;` but field is still not updating. The error displays on the lightning page itself and contains an error id and stating that page has error without giving much details. I also expanded the Technical Stuff but I don't have any idea whatsoever on what it means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115564/discussion-between-arut-and-lol).

Comment: I rechecked again , turns out there's no `event` for `handleSubmit` function. I retained your suggestions earlier, and modified said function to `handleSubmit(event)` and it finally saved the value to the custom field. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: OK. I should probably have mentioned about the `event` param explicitly.

Comment: For future reference; The problem is that readonly input fields somehow aren't saved.
For me a simple workaround was to include 2 lightning-input elements, 1 as readonly and a second without readonly, but hidden: class="slds-hide".